# What exactly is a Principal component and Empirical Orthogonal Function?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am trying to enhance the contrast in the images I get after scanning a surface using Thermography (Principal Component Thermography ~Rajic, which is basically an application of Principal Component Analysis) to see the defects clearly.

But my question here is to understand the difference between empirical orthogonal functions and Principal Components as shown below: [image: figure]
SVD is used to decompose matrix `A` into `U`, `R`, and `V`.

In my case, I have 20 images. And after doing a raster like operation to unroll an image in a column, I get my matrix `A` which has 20 columns and each of them represents one image.

Any intuitive explanation will be really appreciated.

Comment: The column $i$ in $U$ corresponding to the largest diagonal value in $R_{ii}$ is the principal component. That means it is the image that if you use it to approximate an image (if you are only allowed to use one) would on average give the least squared error if trying to reproduce any of the images in $A$.

Comment: I haven't encountered "Empirical orthogonal function" in any literature so far so I wonder how widespread it is. Maybe if you add more context it will be easier to figure out what the author may mean with it.

Comment: @mathreadler This might helps "Orthogonal statistical modes are present in the columns of U known as the empirical orthogonal functions (EOFs) seen in Figure. The first few EOFs describe the largest variability in the thermal sequence and generally only a few EOFs contain useful images. Furthermore orthogonal statistical modes describing time variations are present in the rows of V^T known as principal components (PCs)." Here PCA is applied on a sequence of images, which records the exponential decay of heat on a surface.

Comment: Seems just like an arbitrary expression the author felt a need to come up with to get a sense of accomplishment. The expression in itself is not important. Don't spend too much time on it.